# calling stacks in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a procedure in asp.net web site that gives strange result sometimes, I’m thinking to add some code to track it. My question is, in the production environment, is there any way that I can get the calling stacks like the one in the exceptions?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Environment.StackTrace`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx